# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE how can I tell which records updated and which inserted

Tags: mysql

In a PHP script I'm using the MySQL `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command to insert/update a number of records in my DB. 
Is there anything that MySQL returns to say which records were inserted or updated?

An 'ugly' way would be to do a SELECT before each INSERT and see if the key exists before each INSERT but I'd like to know if MySQL has this function built in.
In case anyone need further info on what I'm trying to do is, to save the record id's to a log.

Answer (score 2):

You will need another `SELECT` regardless, specifically `SELECT ROW_COUNT()`.

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Comment: Seems pretty close to what I'm looking for, I'll give it a try.

Comment: That's good but it won't work with multiple rows in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to tell which records were inserted and which were updated purely with the means provided by MySQL without additional queries. However, you can add a column to the table where you can keep an indicator that you can use to mark the record as updated instead of inserted, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Col1, Col2, Updated)
VALUES ("value1", "value2", 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Col1 = values(Col1),
    Col2 = values(Col2),
    Updated = 1
```

Comment: Thought of that too but it's not up to me to alter the table structure. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I do have to say, the other suggestion about `ROW_COUNT()` is actually better if you're inserting one row per query.